# What energy is transformed to heat when a candle is burned?

Tags: energy, heat

What energy is being transformed to heat when you burn a candle?

Answer (score 3):

This would be chemical energy that is converted to heat. The heat from the wick melts the wax which gets absorbed in the wick and then gets burnt (which is really oxidation) to produce heat energy as well as light energy.

Comment: ""The heat from the wick melts the wax "" Nonsense! The heat conduction by the fabric of the wick is much too small! The wax is molten by radiated heat (IR) !  ""the wax which gets absorbed in the wick"" another nonsense, look up meaning of "absorbed".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are right -- its radiated heat. I learned something from you, bow in your general direction, and stand corrected.

Comment: @Georg: remember that being right doesn't entitle you to be rude ;-)

Comment: @David: Thanks. Anyway I learned something and got a chance to use a Monty Python reference. So not complaining :)

Answer (score -1):

The energy transforms from chemical energy to heat and light energy. Because when the candle burns a chemical reaction occurs, and produces heat and light.

Comment: Not an explanation

Comment: You need to provide more detail about what happens in a chemical reaction.